# How to show that two statements are logically equivalent using different laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to show that

$(\backsim(P\vee Q))\vee(\backsim P\wedge Q)\cong \backsim P.$

I tried like this but do not know how to get the desired result using different laws

L.H.S$=(\backsim(P\vee Q))\vee(\backsim P\wedge Q)$

$=(\backsim(P\vee Q))\vee\backsim(\backsim((\backsim P\wedge Q))$

$=(\backsim(P\vee Q))\vee\backsim(\backsim\backsim P\vee\backsim Q))$ by De-Morgan' law

$=\backsim[(P\vee Q))\wedge( P\vee\backsim Q))]$ because $\backsim\backsim P=P$

I do not know  how to proceed further to get the desired result $\backsim P.$

I can prove this using truth table but do not know how to prove using different laws.

I need in detail answer.

Thank You!

Comment: What are those 'different laws'?   What laws do you have?  And please don't say 'the usual' ...  there are various sets of laws ....

Comment: @Bram28 Sir I am talking about commutative, associative, distributive, idempotent and absorption laws.

Comment: Hmmm.... those aren;lt quite sufficient to do this.  Do you have Adjacency?  Complement? Identity?

Comment: @Bram28 Sir the laws I have mentioned are sufficient to get the desired result. I got it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\neg [(P∨Q))∧(P∨\neg Q)]$ is equivalent to $\neg [P\wedge (Q\vee\neg Q)]$ by distributivity. But $Q\vee \neg Q$ is logically true and so the formula is equivalent to $\neg [P\wedge true]$ which is $\neg P$ as required.

Comment: I know about the distributive law sir but how can we deduce that $\neg[(P\vee Q)\wedge(P\vee \neg Q)]$ is equivalent to $\neg[P\wedge(Q\vee\neg Q)]$?

Comment: Sir I used distributive law and absorption laws and then got the desired result. Thanks